# While trying to install `apt-get install npm`, it shows an error

Tags: npm, apt-get

`Err:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 4.18.0-10.11
  Bad header line Bad header data [IP: 192.168.1.151 808]
Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 libc6-dev amd64 2.28-0ubuntu1 [2,587 kB]`

Any solution to circumvent this roadblock would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you use apt-get for install nodejs you can switch version easily:

```
$ sudo apt-get install npm # install npm
$ sudo npm install -g  n  # install n nodejs version switcher as global package.
$ sudo n stable # install latest stable version.
install more version: [exmp: 9.1.0]

$ sudo n 9.1.0
```